# How to get a Unicode Standard (or other) string representation of the user's date+time format?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I can print out a date nicely based on the user's locale. But how could I get a string with the date+time format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
NSLog(@"The date and time is %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

Comment: Perfect! I was getting an empty string all the time because I didn't explicitely set those styles. wasted 5 hours of my life ;-)